# Facebook Android SDK 4.1+

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I'm upgrading to the latest Android and iOS sdks for Facebook and had two question.

Now that we have a concept of an `access token` that has to be refreshed periodically, I have been reading about the iOS SDK and noticed the below in the SDK:

```
/*!
 @abstract Refresh the current access token's permission state and extend the token's expiration date,
  if possible.
 @param completionHandler an optional callback handler that can surface any errors related to permission refreshing.
 @discussion On a successful refresh, the currentAccessToken will be updated so you typically only need to
  observe the `FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification` notification.

 If a token is already expired, it cannot be refreshed.
 */
+ (void)refreshCurrentAccessToken:(FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)completionHandler;
```

This method is for refreshing the SDK and is in the class `FBSDKAccessToken`. On the Android side I'm trying to find out if the same is true and read the code as well as documentation on this, it doesn't say if the `AccessToken` class's refresh method (`refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync`) has to be called before expiration.

I have read this in the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/

Even for `getLastRefresh()` it says the below:

```
Gets the date at which the token was last refreshed. Since tokens expire, the Facebook SDK will attempt to renew them periodically.
```

This is unlike iOS where refreshing doesn't happen automatically. Is my assumption correct? That the iOS and Android sdks are handling refreshing differently?

Also, what is the best practice for refreshing tokens? I have been refreshing tokens in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in iOS and on Android I do it when the application loads. However, it would help if there was more information on the best strategy with the SDKs.

I have been reading the following on this:

https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4

https://www.quora.com/With-the-Facebook-Graph-API-is-there-a-way-to-get-a-new-access-token-without-needing-to-re-enter-the-users-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access token will get refreshed automatically in the Android SDK if you make a graph request (it gets piggy-backed onto the request that you make).

Comment: It's the same behavior.

Comment: @MingLi, Can you please help me with the following questions? I Googled for this everywhere but did not find appropriate answers. We have a Facebook app created in our developer account.
This app is currently targeting Graph API Version 2.0

1. What is the timeline/date for Graph API Version 2.0? What will be the case if our existing apps are using this version?
Will they still work?
2. What should we do in order to upgrade Graph API Version 2.0 to 2.4 or 2.5? Will this affect our existing apps?
3. What steps need to take in order to migrate from Graph API Version 2.0 to the latest version?

Comment: @MingLi: Continued....4. Our Android apps are using Facebook Android SDK 3.6.0. These apps are using Login, Like and Comment/Share features in the app.
5. What is the expected timeline/deprecation date for Facebook Android SDK 3.6.0?
6. What steps do we need to follow to upgrade the Facebook Android SDK to the latest version? 
Will this affect our existing apps? 
Please suggest the best way to handle these situations.

Comment: The main Graph API documentation page contains answers to all your questions including when the support will last until (see Changelog) and how to upgrade to different versions (Upgrade Guide): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: As for the Android SDK, you should follow the upgrade guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x#3to4